# PySide using GUI elements in another class

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I am making an application in Qt using PySide. In my main.py I have a class called Program which sets up the ui and I have another class which has functions pertaining to a certain area. For instance I have an area which has a start and a clear button.  I define the functions in class RunArea and connect the signals in class Program but nothing happens. Here is the code.

```
class Program(QtGui.QMainWindow, Interface.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Program, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.runArea = RunArea()
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.runArea.start)
        self.clearButton.clicked.connect(self.runArea.clear)


class RunArea(QtGui.QMainWindow, Interface.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(RunArea, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def start(self):
        self.log.setPlainText("log entry")

    def clear(self):
        self.runTree.clear()
```

What I expect to happen is that "log entry" will be put in a QTextEdit(defined in setupUi) when I click start. And when I click clear a TreeWidget with name runTree will be cleared. I know that the signals are working, but nothing is showing up.  May someone please explain why it is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why/how your code isn't working, although I suspect it has something to do with the inheritance not referring to the same object in the both classes.
However, this is how this should be done:

```
class Program(QtGui.QMainWindow, Interface.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Program, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.runArea = RunArea(self)
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.runArea.start)
        self.clearButton.clicked.connect(self.runArea.clear)


class RunArea():
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent

    def start(self):
        self.parent.log.setPlainText("log entry")

    def clear(self):
        self.parent.runTree.clear()
```